# Heaset microphone is not working on my Acer Swift 3

Tags: sound, microphone, audio-jack

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on my Acer swift 3 - SF314-55G. Laptop internal microphone is working fine but my headset microphone is not taking any input. please help.

Comment: Same issue with my Acer Swift SF314-42